# How to modify a find function loop to handle backslashes and whitespaces?

Tags: bash

Currently, I am trying to parse out all the files inside a directory. I have a find function, but it appears to not be able to parse in file directories with whitespaces into a loop. Here, `"$DIR"` is the directory I wish to search in. Does anyone have any ideas how I can modify it to work? thanks.

```
for file in $(find "$DIR" -type f)
do
   echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find ... | xargs ...` and `find ... -exec ...` are both better options than this: to use a shell loop to iterate over find results correctly, we must use a `while read` loop:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do 
    echo "$filename"
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -print0)
```

A lot to unpack there:

- we use a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to execute the find command and be able to read from the results like it's a file.
- To read a line of input verbatim, the bash idiom is `IFS= read -r line`. That allows arbitrary whitespace and backslashes to be read into the variable.
- `read -d ''` uses the null byte (as produced by `-print0`) as the end-of-line character instead of newline.

Comment: Also, don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: it's [too easy to make mistakes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/114596/4667)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to `for` loop this.

```
find "$dir" -type f
```

will by default output all found objects.

You can make this explicit with:

```
find "$dir" -type f -print
```

If you *really* want to iterate over these, use a null separator and `xargs`:

```
find "$dir" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 echo
```

Or `find`'s own `-exec`:

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Comment: If I wanted to pass the filenames found into a function, is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: I'd read the results of `find` into an array (`arr=( $( find [...] ) )`), and reference that array within the function, or pass its contents _to_ the function `func "${arr[@]}"`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti isn't that going to have the same word-splitting issues as the original? See for example [How to pass files found by find as arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318429/65304)

Comment: Yeah, probably.  Let me revise.  I'd probably pass the directory to the function, and let it handle the `find`ing.

Answer (score 4):

You should [not parse the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) for the same reasons you [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Try using `find`/`exec` instead:

```
find "$DIR" -type f -exec echo {} \;
```